# Twilio schema validation warning

Tags: xml, xsd, twilio, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am receiving [schema validation warning](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/12200)

> Warning - 12200
>
> Schema validation warning
>
> The provided XML does not conform to the Twilio Markup XML schema.
>   Please refer to the specific error and correct the problem. Possible
>   Causes
>
> misspelled verbs incorrect case for verbs misspelled or unknown
>   attributes unknown or unexpected nested elements. Possible Solutions
>
> check the line and column reported by the warning to see what part of
>   your XML response caused the complaint

with following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Response>
  <Gather numDigits="1" action="/employee/set_job_type">
    <Say voice="alice" language="en-US">press</Say>
    <Say voice="alice" language="en-US">1 for CREW.</Say>
    <Pause length="0.3" />
    <Say voice="alice" language="en-US">2 for PORTER-MAID.</Say>
    <Pause length="0.3" />
    <Say voice="alice" language="en-US">3 for PROJECT WORK.</Say>
    <Pause length="0.3" />
    <Pause length="5" />
    <Say voice="alice" language="en-US">press</Say>
    <Say voice="alice" language="en-US">4 for CREW.</Say>
    <Pause length="0.3" />
    <Say voice="alice" language="en-US">5 for PORTER-MAID.</Say>
    <Pause length="0.3" />
    <Say voice="alice" language="en-US">6 for PROJECT WORK.</Say>
    <Pause length="0.3" />
    <Pause length="5" />
    <Say voice="alice" language="en-US">press</Say>
    <Say voice="alice" language="en-US">7 for CREW.</Say>
    <Pause length="0.3" />
    <Say voice="alice" language="en-US">8 for PORTER-MAID.</Say>
    <Pause length="0.3" />
    <Say voice="alice" language="en-US">9 for PROJECT WORK.</Say>
    <Pause length="0.3" />
    <Pause length="5" />
  </Gather>
</Response>
```

I can't find spelling mistake or invalid nesting. Only thing I can think of is back to back pause verb usage. However I don't see docs mentioning anything against it.

Comment: **Include the validation warning in your question.**   Creating a [mcve] that includes the XSD too would also be good.

Comment: Your xml is just fine. I just checked with my Twilio number and hosted at http://xmlbin.com/x/mB3_r2/ . Check on your server, content type, xml declaration on the first line, etc... Use a browser to get the xml and look at the source.

Comment: The error message that you pasted is just Twilio's generic wrapper for all XML Schema validation errors.  *You should see (and post!) the actual XML Schema validation error.*

Comment: @MeganSpeir, your edit of the question to add the link to Twilio's generic wrapper was mildly useful; what really would help is if you (as a Twilio rep per your profile) would explain how a user is supposed to get from that wrapper error message to the actual XSD validation error message.

Comment: Hi @kjhughes, yes I'm on the Developer Community team at Twilio. To the best of my knowledge, the xml schema you shared (link fixed) is what is available for testing. That's why I upvoted your answer :) Would love to send you a shirt to say thanks for offering your assistance here. Email mspeir@twilio.com if that sounds cool to you.

Comment: @MeganSpeir:  Oh, just consider it my small contribution to your IPO's success (haha).

Comment: @MeganSpeir: Still wondering, though, (1) why a 12200 warning wouldn't include the specific XSD validation error -- would seem to be very useful to caller -- and (2) why 12200 wouldn't be an error rather than just warning.

Comment: @MeganSpeir could you please check my question too? Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367898/twilio-quick-start-project-is-not-working

Answer (score 2):

You don't link to the governing XSD.  Assuming that it's [here](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/blob/master/src/Twilio.Twiml.Tests/TwiML.xsd), then the following corrected XML will be valid against it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Response  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/master/src/Twilio.Twiml.Tests/TwiML.xsd">
  <Gather numDigits="1" action="/employee/set_job_type">
    <Say voice="woman" language="en">press</Say>
    <Say voice="woman" language="en">1 for CREW.</Say>
    <Pause length="1" />
    <Say voice="woman" language="en">2 for PORTER-MAID.</Say>
    <Pause length="1" />
    <Say voice="woman" language="en">3 for PROJECT WORK.</Say>
    <Pause length="1" />
    <Pause length="5" />
    <Say voice="woman" language="en">press</Say>
    <Say voice="woman" language="en">4 for CREW.</Say>
    <Pause length="1" />
    <Say voice="woman" language="en">5 for PORTER-MAID.</Say>
    <Pause length="1" />
    <Say voice="woman" language="en">6 for PROJECT WORK.</Say>
    <Pause length="1" />
    <Pause length="5" />
    <Say voice="woman" language="en">press</Say>
    <Say voice="woman" language="en">7 for CREW.</Say>
    <Pause length="1" />
    <Say voice="woman" language="en">8 for PORTER-MAID.</Say>
    <Pause length="1" />
    <Say voice="woman" language="en">9 for PROJECT WORK.</Say>
    <Pause length="1" />
    <Pause length="5" />
  </Gather>
</Response>
```