# Twilio quick_start project is not working

Tags: android, heroku, twilio, twilio-api

I'm following [Twilio Quickstart](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/android-client#download-or-check-out-the-quickstart-project) to launch Twilio for the first time. I deployed Twilio on Heroku using [this link](https://github.com/choppen5/twilio-client-quicker-starter). Giving it parameters required like **twilio_account_sid, twilio_auth_token, twilio_caller_id** and **twilio_app_id**. I created a TwiML app and entered my app URL deployed on Heroku to it and set its method to GET.

Then imported Twilio Quickstart project into Android Studio, and set *TOKEN_SERVICE_URL* to my application URL on Heroku. I run the application, got no error but this message on logcat `Device has stopped listening for incoming connections`.

I'm running the app on two devices, register one by another name and try to call it. I get **Capability Token**, but nothing happens. No beeb, no sound, and nothing, but when I try calling using app URL on the browser, a trial warning sound plays and I see a message saying *Call Established Successfully*, then ends immediately without connecting. My account has its initial credit; about $11.0.

I also see a *XML Validation Warning - 12200* in Debugger on Twilio. I tried and searched a lot in four days. Please help me figure out the problem and solve it. I'm waiting for you guys.

Thanks in Advance.

**Edit:** Here is my body response I'm getting in Twilio debugger console:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello Client Monkey Quicker Starter'</title>
        <script type="text/javascript"
      src="//media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/client/v1.3/twilio.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href="//static0.twilio.com/packages/quickstart/client.css"
      type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript">

    Twilio.Device.setup("eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzY29wZSI6InNjb3BlOmNsaWVudDppbmNvbWluZz9jbGllbnROYW1lPWNoYXJsZXMgc2NvcGU6Y2xpZW50Om91dGdvaW5nP2FwcFNpZD1BUDNhYWVlYmVmYWUwMDEyZmVlZGRlOTU3N2FkYzdkNDUxJmNsaWVudE5hbWU9Y2hhcmxlcyIsImlzcyI6IkFDM2UyOGQ0OGRjOWExM2NlMzIzNjZmY2M1OTU1ZmI5OWMiLCJleHAiOjE0OTIzMjc0MzR9.WdnE5GRkM9--MRj9MZlEIjTvGb5U7XXWQj2rBDaj2uE", {debug: true});

      Twilio.Device.ready(function (device) {
        $("#log").text("Client 'charles' is ready");
      });

      Twilio.Device.error(function (error) {
        $("#log").text("Error: " + error.message);
      });

      Twilio.Device.connect(function (conn) {
        $("#log").text("Successfully established call");
      });

      Twilio.Device.disconnect(function (conn) {
        $("#log").text("Call ended");
      });

      Twilio.Device.incoming(function (conn) {
        $("#log").text("Incoming connection from " + conn.parameters.From);
        // accept the incoming connection and start two-way audio
        conn.accept();
      });

      function call() {
        // get the phone number or client to connect the call to
        params = {"PhoneNumber": $("#number").val()};
        Twilio.Device.connect(params);
      }

      function hangup() {
        Twilio.Device.disconnectAll();
      }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="call" onclick="call();">
      Call
    </button>
        <button class="hangup" onclick="hangup();">
      Hangup
    </button>
        <input type="text" id="number" name="number"
      placeholder="Enter a phone number or
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your XML? When I was running into a similar issue my XML was invalid.

Comment: I don't know where is the XML file. I just deployed twilio using four parameters. I heroku also I can't see any file to change / manage them. Can you tell me please where is it?

Comment: Isn't any support for this product? What is going on?

Comment: If you go into the debugger and inspect the 12200 error you got, it should show you the body of the response Twilio received from your application. Can you find that and post it as an edit to your question. Then we can try to solve it.

Comment: @philnash edited question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

So, the problem you have is that your TwiML application is pointing to the wrong path on your application. You're currently pointing at the root path `/` which actually returns the front end of the application. You need to update your TwiML application to point to the URL you have deployed it at and the path `/voice`.